# How to share sessions data between Symfony controllers and classic stand alone php script where sessions are managed in memcache?

Tags: php, symfony, session, memcached, share

I have a site built on Symfony framework and I had to add a legacy php script launched directly in the web directory.

I also have to share session's data between the Symfony framework controllers and the stand-alone php script.

Sessions on my server and the Symfony framework are configured to be in a memcached server (127.0.0.1 11211).

Here are my Symfony config files :

parameters.yml

```
session_memcached_host: 127.0.0.1
session_memcached_port: 11211
session_memcached_prefix: 'BPY_'
session_memcached_expire: 3600
```

config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: session.yml }

    ...

    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.memcached
```

session.yml

```
services:
    session.memcached:
        class: Memcache
        arguments:
            persistent_id: %session_memcached_prefix%
        calls:
            - [ addServer, [ %session_memcached_host%, %session_memcached_port% ]]

    session.handler.memcached:
       class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcacheSessionHandler
       arguments: [@session.memcached, { prefix: %session_memcached_prefix%, expiretime: %session_memcached_expire% }]
```

Session in the Symfony controllers are set and read using :

```
$request->getSession->get('key');
$request->getSession->set('key', $value);
```

In the stand-alone old php script, I use the global session array to set and get data. And in theory, to allow Symfony and my script share data I set and get data in :

```
$_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']
```

So, finally with this configuration, when I set data in the symfony controllers I do not see it in the stand-alone php script and when I set data in the php script I do not see it in the Symfony controllers.

What is wrong in my configuration or my code?

Answer (score 2):

You should check the [Bridge a legacy Application with Symfony Sessions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/php_bridge.html)
but overall you can configure it in the following way:

```
framework:
  session:
    storage_id: session.storage.php_bridge
    handler_id: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem.

In the parameters.yml file I put :

```
session_memcached_prefix : ''
```

instead of :

```
session_memcached_prefix : 'BPY_'
```

and the two envirennements can share sessions data.

In the Symfony controllers I still use

```
$request->getSession->get('key');
$request->getSession->set('key', $value);
```

And in the stand-alone php script I use set and get data in this array :

```
$_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']
```

So

```
$_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']['key'] = $value
```